# Cant add if statement php

Tags: php

Hi im posting a textarea value to a page and the value must equal "2011" if it doesnt I want to throw an error.

my input is

```
<fieldset>
    <span class="subtitle">What year is it?</span>
    <input type="text" name="aspam" id="aspam"/>
</fieldset>
```

and my php is

```
if(!isset($_POST['produgg_username']) or !isset($_POST['produgg_password']) or           !isset($_POST['produgg_email']) or $_POST['aspam'] != '2011')
{
    print "Please use all fields";
}elseif(empty($_POST['produgg_username'])){
    print "Please choose a username";
}elseif($_POST['aspam'] != '2011'){
    print "its not 2011!";
}elseif(empty($_POST['produgg_password'])){
    print "Please choose a password";
}elseif(empty($_POST['produgg_email'])){
    print "Please enter an email address";
}elseif(!filter_var($_POST['produgg_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {    
    print "Please enter a valid email address";
}elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", $_POST['produgg_username'])) {
    print "Please use only characters and numbers for username";
}elseif($usersClass->checkUserExists($_POST['produgg_username'])) {
   print "Username Taken, please choose another";
```

Comment: You're missing a closing brace

Comment: I just LOVE forms that do sequential validation. Enter a field, submit, get an error, fix field, submit, get yet another error... so user friendly!

Comment: How come its not working? its not saying the year 2011when i input 2019 or something

Comment: Really? You set `$_POST['aspam']  = '2019'` and you wonder why its `!= '2011'`?

Comment: No when i input 2019, it should say "The year is not 2019 but it doesnt

Comment: if the value doesnt == 2011 it needs to error

Comment: You have `or $_POST['aspam'] != '2011'` in your first `if` condition, which will error as `print "Please use all fields";`. You never make it to the `print "its not 2011!";` condition because you've already exited the if else if chain

Answer (score 3):

A closing `}` is missing at the end.

```
   }elseif($usersClass->checkUserExists($_POST['produgg_username'])) {
     print "Username Taken, please choose another";
   }
 ^^^^^ --- add this brace
```

Comment: Now the question is closed, but: